# Cost efficient algorithm to group array of sets

Tags: arrays, algorithm, set

Can anyone help me out with some effectively good algorithm to carry out the following task:

I got a file of unique row numbers with an array of integer numbers per row.

I need to check each single row for the values of an array that show up in different rows and put them in one group. Here is an example how it may look:

Row Number; Array of data[...]

```
L1; [1,2,3,4,5]
L2; [2,3]
L3: [8,9]
L4: [6]
L5; [7]
L6; [5,6]
```

Based on these input data, I expect the algorithm to produce the result:

Group N; Array of rows [...]

```
G1; [L1,L2,L4,L6]
G2; [ L3]
G3; [ L5]
```

P.S the original dataset accounts for hundreds of millions of rows and can contain close to a million of array elements... time efficiency is a concern.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how the output relates to the input - can you give some code or pseudocode to illustrate what needs to be done?

Comment: As you can see Group 1 has all uniq rows from Row #1,#2,#4 and #6 as row #2 has digits [2,3], row #4 has digit 6, which is also in row #6 with digit 5 which is in row #1. So we basically grouping by the same values recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is equivalent to finding connected components of a graph in which:

1. The vertices correspond to the initial row numbers
2. There is an edge between two vertices x and y if there is a common element in the array for x and the array for y

This can be done efficiently using a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) as follows:

1. `MakeSet(d)` for each of the data values d (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in your example)
2. For each row with array A, call `join(A[0],A[i])` for each choice of i.

This will produce a set for each connected component.  You can then produce your output array by iterating over the rows a second time:

```
set output to an array of empty lists
for each row r
    A = array for row r
    id = find(A[0])
    output[id].append(r)
```

### Example Python Code

```
from collections import defaultdict
data=[[1,2,3,4,5],
      [2,3],
      [8,9],
      [6],
      [7],
      [5,6]]
N=max(max(A) for A in data)
rank=[0]*(N+1)
parent=range(N+1)

def Find(x):
    """Find representative of connected component"""
    if  parent[x] != x:
        parent[x] = Find(parent[x])
    return parent[x]

def Union(x,y):
    """Merge sets containing elements x and y"""
    x = Find(x)
    y = Find(y)
    if x == y:
        return
    if rank[x]<rank[y]:
        parent[x] = y
    elif rank[x]>rank[y]:
        parent[y] = x
    else:
        parent[y] = x
        rank[x] += 1

# First join all data
for row,A in enumerate(data):
    for x in A:
        Union(A[0],x)

# Then place rows into sets
D=defaultdict(list)
for row,A in enumerate(data):
    D[Find(A[0])].append(row+1)

# Then display output
for i,L in enumerate(D.values()):
    print i+1,L
```

Running this code prints the output:

```
1 [3]
2 [1, 2, 4, 6]
3 [5]
```

Comment: I'm afraid of situation when there's no direct edge. E.g. L1:[1,2,3] L2:[4,5] L3:[5,6] L4:[6,1], as you can see there's no direct edge between L1 and L2, they are connected only through L4 which connects L3 and L2. Which leads to recursion. The thing is they can be connected through N unknown edges.

Comment: @Nate I believe this case will still work fine.  When we process L1 we merge 1,2,3 into set A, then (L2) we merge 4,5 into set B, then (L3) we merge 6 into set B, then (L4) we merge sets A and B into a single set.

Comment: Trying to understand what you have written, can you help a bit with any pseudo-code written on python or ruby?